# Azure AD Daemon App Application Permission and id_token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like to register a daemon App and grant it application permission for the Microsoft graph API.
Now from my client i will pass in the client_id and secret to the endpoint and do a call like this
app.acquire_token_for_client

I end up getting an access token but not an id_token.

Is there any way to get an id_token when my client is an daemon app and not an actual end user ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with daemon applications, you will end up using Client Credentials Grant flow as described [here on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). (as you've mentioned using client_id and secret)

Azure AD endpoints will not issue an id_token in this case, so you will not be able to get it when using your daemon app.

id_token is relevant in other flows like when using OpenID connect as described here on Microsoft Docs: [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc)

Answer (score 1):

By the way MS Graph permissions doesn't work properly right now.

- **one** https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f6eb4f0b-df32-432e-8b24-f248a3b7659c/the-portal-is-having-issues-getting-an-authentication-token-the-experience-rendered-may-be?forum=windowsazuremanagement
- **two**
  [image]